# Create blinking "text" in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, blink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Text blinking jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605698/text-blinking-jquery)

I'm trying to create a timer in my HTML5/JavaScript game when the game is over. Something like 3...2...1.. where 3 will appear then flash, then 2, then flash, then 1, then flash and return back to my title screen... Nothing I put will get that to work... Anybody able to help me out here? So far my code for the numbers is this:

```
function CreateTimer(){
    timer =  setInterval(function() {
    cntxt.fillText(time, c.width/2 - cntxt.measureText(time).width/2, c.height/4);
    time--;
    }, 1000);

}

function resetTimer(){
clearInterval(timer);
time = 3;
where = "menu";
}
```

But even this will just place the 2nd number and then 3rd number straight over the previous and then return the title as expected.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the text first see http://www.w3schools.com/html5/canvas_clearrect.asp

Comment: Yes, I have tried doing that but I guess I'm not doing it right because adding the clearRect is just clearing it but not retyping the text once the interval is called again.

Comment: You need to clear it just before you draw another text put it just above cntxt.fillText