# How to make this Jquery-blinking background stop after a few seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make this Jquery-blinking background stop after a few seconds? I'm trying to set the background and text to blink and then stop after 3 seconds. Thanks for your help in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  blinkFont();
});

function blinkFont() {
  document.getElementById("blink").style.color = "red"
  document.getElementById("blink").style.background = "black"
  setTimeout("setblinkFont()", 500)
}

function setblinkFont() {
  document.getElementById("blink").style.color = "black"
  document.getElementById("blink").style.background = "red"
  setTimeout("blinkFont()", 500)
}
```

```css
#blink {
  text-align: center;
  background: #000000;
  color: #F00;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
#blink span {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="blink"><span>This is blinking text and background</span>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text blinking jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605698/text-blinking-jquery)

Comment: @Sadikhasan it will not stop the blinking after sometime

Comment: use setInterval and clearInterval?

Comment: Yeah I'm also trying to stop the blinking background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I could think of a few more elegant ways to do this, without changing your current structure *too much*, you could store the Timeouts in variables and then use [clearInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) , which stops a timer, to stop the recurrences after three seconds:

```
<script>
var intervalA;
var intervalB;

$(document).ready(function() {

  blinkFont();
  setTimeout(function() {

      clearInterval(intervalA); clearInterval(intervalB);},3000);
});

function blinkFont() {
  document.getElementById("blink").style.color = "red"
  document.getElementById("blink").style.background = "black"
  intervalA = setTimeout("setblinkFont()", 500);
}

function setblinkFont() {
  document.getElementById("blink").style.color = "black"
  document.getElementById("blink").style.background = "red"
  intervalB = setTimeout("blinkFont()", 500);
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="blink"><span>This is blinking text and background</span>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [SetTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) , [SetInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) and [clearInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) as below code.

**[Click Here to see working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/fx337L48/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="blink"><span>Demo</span>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var myVar;
        myVar = setInterval(blinkFont, 500); 

        function blinkFont() {
    var curColor = document.getElementById("blink").style.color;
    var curBgC = document.getElementById("blink").style.background;
    document.getElementById("blink").style.color = curColor === "red" ? "blue" : "red";
    document.getElementById("blink").style.background = curBgC === "black" ? "yellow" : "black";

}
        setTimeout(function () {
                         $("#blink").css('visibility', 'visible');
            clearInterval(myVar);        
                    }, 3000); // after 3 seconds it'll stop blinking
    });
```

**[Here is Working JsFiddle - Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/fx337L48/1/)**

Comment: @AllforAurora - Check out the Js Fiddle- it's Working as you want

Comment: @AllforAurora - Glad to help you :) - if answer is useful then `accept` the answer and `upvote` it will helps other to find correct solutions

Answer (score 0):

Instead of SetTimeout use SetInterval, keep the variable with you. And keep a counter, which will be incremented after every execution, once you reach the desired number of repetition, stopinterval.
Something like this:

```
 myVar=setInterval("javascript function", milliseconds);

//check your counter value.
 window.clearInterval(myVar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/6g3hwLz5/) satisfied you?

code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var intval;
    intval = setInterval(function(){
       blinkFont(); 
    },500);

    setTimeout(function() {

          alert('clear');
            clearInterval(intval);
    }, 3000);



});

function blinkFont() {
    var curColor = document.getElementById("blink").style.color;
    var curBgC = document.getElementById("blink").style.background;
    document.getElementById("blink").style.color = curColor === "red" ? "blue" : "red";
    document.getElementById("blink").style.background = curBgC === "black" ? "yellow" : "black";

}
```