# Blinking Text that Can Also Be Hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to use blinking text to signify that data is loading. Then 
hide it once the data is loaded.

I'm also using Flask.

I'm a JQuery newbie and found a recipe for flashing text, but it has the side effect, that hide didn't work.

[SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605698/text-blinking-jquery)

```
setInterval(function() {
    $( "#blink" ).fadeToggle();
}, 500);
```

The I tried to hide after loading data into a div.

```
$("#data").load("/load_data/", function() {
    $("#blink").hide('fast')
});
```

HTML:

```
<p id="blink">Loading Data</p>
<div id="data"></div>
```

Does this not work or am I just screwing it up...?
Is there another simple solution ?

TIA !!
Happy NY's

UPDATE:

Debugging Andrew Brooke's answer customized for a callback on load.

```
$("#data").load("/load_data/", function() {
    $.clearInterval(blink);
    $("#blink).hide("fast")
});
```

Comment: Believe it or not, there is an HTML tag called <blink> that was deprecated about 15 years ago, but it still works in some browsers. I'm kidding, please don't actually use that, but its a fun fact. <marquee> still works on some as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign your interval to a variable, then clear it in the `.load` callback with `clearInterval`. Then you can hide the blinking text with `.hide`

```
var blink = setInterval(function() {
  $('#blink').fadeToggle();
}, 500);

$('#data').load('/load_data/', function() {
  clearInterval(blink);
  $('#blink').hide('fast');
});
```

Here's a working example

```js
var blink = setInterval(function() {
  $('#blink').fadeToggle();
}, 500);

$('#hide').on('click', function() {
  clearInterval(blink);
  $('#blink').hide('fast');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Hide" id="hide">
<p id="blink">
  This is blinking
</p>
```

Comment: having difficulty with syntax for load callback.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. I did miss a semicolon in my code though, so check that

Comment: thanks again ! This learning project has been intense and not possible without people like yourself....cheers

Answer (score 0):

You forgot some quotation marks.

```
("#data").load("/load_data/", function() {
  $("#blink").hide('fast')
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2pf8v0nc/1/

Comment: I'm pretty sure he made a typo, this doesn't seem to work

Comment: Are you saying my JSFiddle doesn't work? Cause it's not suppose to load anything. Which I guess makes it kinda pointless...

Comment: You're right about the quotation marks, but that doesn't solve the problem. Take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7beoqL19/). Hiding it doesn't keep the element hidden, because the interval is still repeating